# Setting up a Function on Powershell to read from the CSV and then incorporate a switch into it. ActiveDirectory

Tags: function, csv, powershell, active-directory, return

Apologies if the title doesn't make a whole lot of sense as it's hard to word something like this.

So I've been tasked with running a CSV file which will be imported into Powershell, with the aim to bulk create Global Security groups, whilst pulling the information from these headers - RoleName, Description, OUID, Members, Resources.

These groups will act as job roles for users and contain all the permission these users will need on ActiveDirectory.

Here is the script so far (NOT CLOSE TO COMPLETION I'M AWARE).

```
Function GetOU ($OUID) 
{ 
$roleou =
switch ($OUID)
{

1 {"OU=Sales,OU=RoleBasedGroups,OU=Global Security Groups,OU=Org,DC=Company,DC=local"}

2 {"OU=Finance,OU=UK,OU=RoleBasedGroups,OU=Global Security Groups,OU=Org,DC=Company,DC=local"}

3 {"OU=Human Resource,OU=UK,OU=RoleBasedGroups,OU=Global Security Groups,OU=Org,DC=Company,DC=local"}

4 {"OU=Marketing,OU=UK,OU=RoleBasedGroups,OU=Global Security Groups,OU=Org,DC=Company,DC=local"}

}
}
return $OUID

Function NewRole ($Name._){ 
New-ADGroup -GroupCategory:"Security" -GroupScope:"Global" -Description:$Description -Name: $RoleName -Path: GetOU($OUID) -SamAccountName:$RoleName

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $role -Members: $members

Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity:$role -MemberOf: $resources

($newroles = import-csv(c:\test.csv -delimiter ':'))
foreach($newrole in $newroles)
{
     NewRole($._)

     $check = [ADSI]::Exists("$($newrole.$OUID),$($searchbase)")

     If ($check -eq $True)
  {
    Try
    {
      #Check if the Group already exists
      $exists = Get-ADGroup $NewRole.$RoleName
      Write-Host "Group $($NewRole.$RoleName) already exists! Group creation skipped!"
    }
    Catch
    {
      #Create the group if it doesn't exist
      $create = New-ADGroup -Name $RoleName.GroupName -GroupScope:"Global" -Path ($($OUID.GroupLocation)+","+$($searchbase))
      Write-Host "Group $($RoleName.GroupName) created!"
    }
  }
  Else
  {
    Write-Host "Target OU can't be found! Group creation skipped!"
  }
}
}
```

CSV looks like this:

```
RoleName:Description:OUID:Members:Resources
gs_r_UK_SalesAdmin:UK - Sales Admin:1:John.Smith:Domain Users,GoogleApps
```

I was wondering if the Return $OUID is in the right place, as I'm currently struggling to get that part running.

Thanks for taking time to read this and any recommendations on how to improve this script to read simpler would be MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Return $OUID` was outside the `GetOU`-function, but I would skip it all together as you don't want the OUID, but rather the OU-path. Ex.

```
$data = @"
RoleName:Description:OUID:Members:Resources
gs_r_UK_SalesAdmin:UK - Sales Admin:1:John.Smith:Domain Users,GoogleApps
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ":"

Function GetOU ($OUID) 
{ 
    switch ($OUID) {

        1 {"OU=Sales,OU=RoleBasedGroups,OU=Global Security Groups,OU=Org,DC=Company,DC=local"}

        2 {"OU=Finance,OU=UK,OU=RoleBasedGroups,OU=Global Security Groups,OU=Org,DC=Company,DC=local"}

        3 {"OU=Human Resource,OU=UK,OU=RoleBasedGroups,OU=Global Security Groups,OU=Org,DC=Company,DC=local"}

        4 {"OU=Marketing,OU=UK,OU=RoleBasedGroups,OU=Global Security Groups,OU=Org,DC=Company,DC=local"}

    }
}


GetOU $data[0].OUID
```

Returns:

```
OU=Sales,OU=RoleBasedGroups,OU=Global Security Groups,OU=Org,DC=Company,DC=local
```

There's alot to fix in the rest of the script, so to avoid going too off-topic here, I figured I should only answer what you asked.

A few tips:

- Powershell syntax for calling functions/cmdlets is ex. `GetOU -OUID 1`.
- There's nothing called `$._` or `$name._`.

  - `$_` is the current object in a `foreach/where/select-object {}`-scriptblock
  - You used `foreach($newrole in ..)` so you would use `$newrole` to reference the current object in the newroles-loop.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i'm aware it needs a lot of tidying up. I'll take on board what you've said :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO. You are trying to `return` from outside the **GetOU** function. You need to put the return statement within the curly brace that completes the function definition.

Your next problem in the **getOU** function is that you are returning the $OUID variable, i.e. the input parameter, when you want to return the OU string I assume. You need to return the **$roleou** variable.

```
Function GetOU { 
  param ($OUID)

  $RoleOU = switch ($OUID) {

    1 {"OU=Sales,OU=RoleBasedGroups,OU=Global Security Groups,OU=Org,DC=Company,DC=local"}

    2 {"OU=Finance,OU=UK,OU=RoleBasedGroups,OU=Global Security Groups,OU=Org,DC=Company,DC=local"}

    3 {"OU=Human Resource,OU=UK,OU=RoleBasedGroups,OU=Global Security Groups,OU=Org,DC=Company,DC=local"}

    4 {"OU=Marketing,OU=UK,OU=RoleBasedGroups,OU=Global Security Groups,OU=Org,DC=Company,DC=local"}

  }
  return $RoleOU
}
```